# draw one image above another code not working

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, cgcontext

I have 2 images of same size and I need to make 3d picture in which 2nd is above 1st
I have UIImage class extension with following method

```
+(UIImage*)imageFrom2Images:(UIImage *)img1 with:(UIImage *)img2 {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img1.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIGraphicsPushContext(context);      
[img1 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[img2 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsPopContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return resultingImage;

}
```

I've tried to save resulting image in Photo Album but it calls error and not working..It seems that this method is wrong.

```
   UIImage*t1=[self.mw.imageFIFO lastObject];
   UIImage* test=[UIImage imageFrom2Images:self.imageView.image with:t1];
   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(test, self,
          @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

The error message I am getting is:

```
 Error Domain=ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain Code=-3304 "Failed to encode image for saved photos." 
 UserInfo=0x9398960 {NSUnderlyingError=0x935e760 "Failed to encode image for saved photos.", 
 NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to encode image for saved photos.}
```

Comment: What error? Where's the error in the posted code?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe   Its posted in image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo: method

Comment: So where's the code? What's the message?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe   Error Domain=ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain Code=-3304 "Failed to encode image for saved photos." UserInfo=0x9398960 {NSUnderlyingError=0x935e760 "Failed to encode image for saved photos.", NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to encode image for saved photos.}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never need to get the current graphics context and then push it - you're just duplicating the top of the context stack.  It would be nice if it still worked, but it doesn't.  Remove the calls to `UIGraphicsPushContext` and `UIGraphicsPopContext`, and it works as intended.

```
+(UIImage*)imageFrom2Images:(UIImage *)img1 with:(UIImage *)img2 {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img1.size);
    [img1 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    [img2 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resultingImage;
}
```

To detect these problems in future, check the output from `imageFrom2Images`.  As originally implemented, it returned `nil`, so it's not surprising that the following calls didn't know what to do.  (If it had returned an image object, the next step would be to display it inside a UIImageView, to make sure it's the *correct* image.)

Answer (score 0):

**This method should do it:**

```
-(UIImage *)drawFirstImage:(UIImage*)firstImage afterSecondImage:(UIImage *)secondImage
{

    float finalWidth=MAX(firstImage.size.width,secondImage.size.width);
    float finalHeight=firstImage.size.height +  secondImage.size.height;

    CGSize finalSize=CGSizeMake(finalWidth, finalHeight);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(finalSize);

    [firstImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, firstImage.size.width, firstImage.size.height)];
    [secondImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, firstImage.size.height, secondImage.size.width, secondImage.size.height)];
    UIImage *resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resultImage;
}
```

**You can use it as:**

```
 UIImage *resultImage= [self drawFirstImage:image1 afterSecondImage:image2];
```

**Here it is a category implementation:**

*UIImage+MyExtensions.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage (MyExtensions)
-(UIImage *)attachImageBelow:(UIImage *)secondImage;
@end
```

*UIImage+MyExtensions.m*

```
#import "UIImage+MyExtensions.h"

@implementation UIImage (MyExtensions)

-(UIImage *)attachImageBelow:(UIImage *)secondImage{
    float finalWidth=MAX(self.size.width,secondImage.size.width);
    float finalHeight=self.size.height +  secondImage.size.height;

    CGSize finalSize=CGSizeMake(finalWidth, finalHeight);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(finalSize);

    [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height)];
    [secondImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, self.size.height, secondImage.size.width, secondImage.size.height)];
    UIImage *resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resultImage;
}
```

**You can use it like this:**

```
#import "UIImage+MyExtensions.h"
UIImage *resultImage= [image1 attachImageBelow:image2];
```